# Extract 3 arrays of data from Array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a array of JSON objects defined as follow:

```
[
    {   
        key : "test1",
        data : {
            "Mercedes" : {
                "ClassA" : [1, 2],
                "ClassB" : [1]
            },
            "Benz" : {
                "ClassA" : [1]]
            }
        }
    },
    {   
        key : "test2",
        data : {
            "Mercedes" : {
                "ClassA" : [1, 2, 3],
                "ClassB" : [1]
            },
            "Toty" : {
                "ClassA" : [1]]
            }
        }
    },...
]
```

I would like to retrieve 3 distincts arrays:

- One containing the name of distinct names that exist in all objects : `result = ["Mercedes", "Benz", "Toty"]`
- One containing all distinct values of type: `type = ["ClassA", "ClassB"]`
- One containing all distinct values of numbers : `numbers = ["1", "2", "3"]`

How can i retrieve these 3 arrays without needed to right multiple loops ?

Comment: Would you write the code using multiple loops and post that code?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON object" – JSON is always a string.

Comment: it's an object written in JSON :P

Comment: No it isn't. It would be invalid JSON. It is a JavaScript literal. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Object_literal_notation_vs_JSON

Comment: You'll have to write a bunch of loops, and most of them will begin with Object.keys.  I firmly believe that object property names should be known to the code that's consuming the object, ie "Mercedes" isn't a good property name, "carname" might be.

Comment: @trincot - Yes it is.. JS literals are written in JSON.. JSON is a *notation*... it's the *notation* Javascript objects are written in..

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. How did we ever manage with our javascript objects before JSON existed?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce, OK, I have to spell it out then: the property names are not all quoted, so it's not even JSON compatible. Invalid as JSON if you really want to use that acronym.

Comment: @James - Are you being facitious or do you not know what the acronym means?

Comment: Taking @trincot's side here... This is a javascript literal, definitely not json. 

That being said, technically there IS a such thing as a JSON object... as a string is an object ;)

Comment: In the JavaScript world, the JSON object has a `parse` and `stringify` method.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Yes I was being a bit facetious.  JSON is always contained in a string, regardless of whether the underlying representation is a primative, array, object, or combination.  I blame Crockford for the confusion.   You might take the acronym at face value, but *JSON* is *a data exchange specification*, and not a notation.

Answer (score 1):

This is not perfect, could be done in cleaner more "JS-y" ways, but here ya go

```
var someArray = ...; // your input array
var uniqueCars = new Set();
var uniqueClasses = new Set();
for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
   // iterate through all prop names
   for (var carProp in someArray[i].data) {
       uniqueCars.add(carProp);

       for (var classProp in someArray[i].data[carProp]) {
           uniqueClasses.add(classProp);

           // Too lazy to do the last one, hopefully you can figure it out
       }
   }    
}

var finalCars = Array.from(uniqueCars);
var finalClasses = Array.from(uniqueClasses);
// do the 3rd one you asked for
```

Comment: Also, obligatory "be careful when using for ... in in javascript". It'll iterate through all iterable properties, so if you don't know exactly what your object looks like, it can do some really unintended things. More info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) - one of the many possible ways you can do it.

```js
var data = [{
    key: "test1",
    data: {
      "Mercedes": {
        "ClassA": [1, 2],
        "ClassB": [1]
      },
      "Benz": {
        "ClassA": [1]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    key: "test2",
    data: {
      "Mercedes": {
        "ClassA": [1, 2, 3],
        "ClassB": [1]
      },
      "Toty": {
        "ClassA": [1]
      }
    }
  }
];

var thing = data.reduce((acc, itm) => {
  for (var type in itm.data) {
    if (acc.types.indexOf(type) === -1) acc.types.push(type);
    for (var cls in itm.data[type]) {
      if (acc.classes.indexOf(cls) === -1) acc.classes.push(cls);
      for (var i = itm.data[type][cls].length; i--;)
        if (acc.numbers.indexOf(itm.data[type][cls][i]) === -1)
          acc.numbers.push(itm.data[type][cls][i]);
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, {
  types: [],
  numbers: [],
  classes: []
});


console.log('Unique Types', thing.types);
console.log('Unique Numbers', thing.numbers);
console.log('Unique Classes', thing.classes);
```

Comment: Yeah, the idea behind this one is cleaner than mine. I was just going to say write 3 different reduce functions, it's not as if you're going to run into any major performance concerns anyway unless your lists are huge...
That being said, if reductions are hard to conceptualize, might be easier to go with a simple loop like what I did below.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a proof of concept, but I think it can be made a recursive function and be more elegant.

```js
let arr = [{ key: "test1", data: { "Mercedes": { "ClassA": [1, 2], "ClassB": [1] }, "Benz": { "ClassA": [1] } } }, { key: "test2", data: { "Mercedes": { "ClassA": [1, 2, 3], "ClassB": [1] }, "Toty": { "ClassA": [1] } } }],

  flatten = (a, b) => [...a, ...b],
  allUnq = a => [...new Set(a.reduce(flatten))],

  data = arr.map(o => o.data),
  vals = d => d.map(Object.values),
  keys = d => d.map(Object.keys),
  
  arr1 = allUnq(keys(data)),
  arr2 = allUnq(vals(data).map(keys).map(allUnq)),
  arr3 = allUnq(allUnq(vals(allUnq(vals(data)))));

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```